# Multipartfile in java dto

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, file-upload

> My requirement is, I would like to get json data along with file.
>   **User can upload file and send his data as (eg. name, email, image);**

I have a simple DTO looks like this (below)

```
public class SampleDTO {

    private String sample1;
    private MultipartFile file;

    public String getSample1() {
        return sample1;
    }
    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setSample1(String sample1) {
        this.sample1 = sample1;
    }
    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

I have a sample API look like this (below)

```
@PostMapping("/sampleAPI")
public void sampleAPI(@RequestBody SampleDTO sampleDto) {
 log.info("sampleDto"+sampleDto);
 log.info("sampleDtoFile"+sampleDto.getFile());
 log.info("sampleDtoSample1"+sampleDto.getSample1());
}
```

If I call this API, No logs are printed and I get this type of error  (`Internal server error`). What I am doing wrong here ?

I used Postman's `formdata` as body, and in javascript `new FormData()` as API body.

Comment: have you tried @ModelAttribute instead of @Requestbody?

Comment: Or else you can also try to store path of Server and fetch MultiPartFile From Server
@Vinay

Comment: @MOnkey Yup! I tried `@ModelAttribute` it basically converts each `DTO` keys to `@RequestParam`. But what if I have some 25 keys in `DTO`, so my API url looks like this `sampleAPI?sample1=test+sample2..so on`.

Comment: @Vinay Johnwesly , but yours is a POST request?

Comment: @MOnkey Yes it is POST request, but you suggested to use `@ModelAttribute`, So I tried that and this is what the result is (It converts every DTO key to param)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@Requestbody`use `@RequestParam`to get your MultiPart Mix formDate.

```
@PostMapping("/sampleAPI")
public String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
                       @RequestParam("sample1") String sample1 ) {
    SampleDTO sampleDto = new SampleDTO ();
    sampleDto.setSample1(sample1);
    sampleDto.setFile(file);
    return sample1 + "\n" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "\n" + file.getSize();
}
```

For multiple keys try using `@RequestParam` along with `Converter`, something like this.

```
@Component
public class StringToSampleDTOConverter implements Converter<String, SampleDTO> {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public SampleDTO convert(String source) {
      return objectMapper.readValue(source, SampleDTO.class);
    }
}

@PostMapping("/sampleAPI")
public String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
                   @RequestParam("sampleDto") SampleDTO sampleDto ) {
    sampleDto.setFile(file);
    return sampleDto + "\n" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "\n" + file.getSize();
}
```

Comment: For demo purposes, I added only 1 key to DTO, but actually I have some 25 keys. Its not a good idea to use request param for 25 keys. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: I guess you need to use @RequestParam along with Converter(https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) for JSON objects.

Comment: @Vinay Johnwesly, have you tried my edited solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can not send the mutli-part file inside an object when passing on request to APIs. Try passing all parameters as REQUEST PARAMETERS as part of the request separately.

Also do not forget to make changes in your APIs accordingly as mentioned above.

When using Postman make sure in body you are under form-data with keys and values passed on. Also mark keys with their appropriate types(text/file). SCREENSHOT BELOW

[image]